# copyFile() method is not present in FileUtils package

Tags: selenium

I am trying to take screenshot in selenium.

I have imported `"org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils"` this package and still i cannot find the `copyFile()` method in the `FileUtils` package.

Its throwing the error as

> "Method is undefined for the type string"

.

Please help.

```
    File DestFile=new File("F:\\Screenshots"+tr.getName()+".png");

    try {

    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, DestFile);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The method `copyFile(File, File)` is undefined for the type String

Comment: Please provide more your code, how to initialize `scrFile` and `tr` in `tr.getName()`?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the functions available for copyFile. You must be passing any one argument/parameter as string.

```
copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile)
copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, boolean preserveFileDate)
copyFile(File input, OutputStream output)
```

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency to pom.xml and then import org.apache.commons.io.*
you will find FileUtils.copyfile

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

cant see the whole Code, but my guess is your srcFile is actually a String and the Method copyFile requires (FILE,FILE).